# Received unregistered task of type xx. The message has been ignored and discarded

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a django project on an ubuntu EC2 node, that performs a computationally intensive long running process, that typically takes over 60 seconds. I need to cache the results. I've been reading http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/06/23/scheduling-tasks-celery/ and http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/ along with the docs. I've been able to get a basic task working at the command line, but  now I'm trying to get it going as a django script.

Right now the structure of my code in my django tp1 view is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):

    token = str(request.POST.get('token', False))
    calculator(token)
    return HttpResponse(token)

@shared_task
def calculator(token):

    # do calculation
    # store result in cache

    return
```

At the command line I ran:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

At the end of the message I got:

```
[2015-03-24 19:49:47,045: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'tp1.views.calculator'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.    Did you remember to import the module containing this task? Or maybe you are using relative imports?
```

My tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import    

from celery import shared_task    

@shared_task
def test(param):
    return 'The test task executed with argument "%s" ' % param
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you are using `autodiscover` Celery may not be able to `autodiscover` your `tasks.py` file. Did you configure it [according to the docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) by creating a `celery_app` file for it to `autodiscover` your tasks:

```
# project/celery_app.py
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('project_name')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
# YOUR APPLICATION MUST BE LISTED IN settings.INSTALLED_APPS for this to work
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

In addition, if you are relying on `autodiscover`, it typically can't find stuff located in modules that are not called `tasks.py`.

Thus, in addition to checking your configuration, I would try moving that task that's in your `views.py` to the `tasks.py`:

```
 # project/app_name/tasks.py
 from celery_app import app
 @app.task()
 def calculator(token):

    # do calculation
    # store result in cache

    return
```

And, finally, you can import this function from `tasks.py` and call it in your view.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You got it working! Like you said I moved the calculator function to tasks.py and imported it into my django views. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Celery is a bit magical but it makes sense when you get used to it.